# how to make react checkbox disabled when value from api is true

Tags: reactjs

I have a checkbox and want it to be checked and disabled when the value from api is true.
It is disabling the checkbox correctly but the box is not checked. What am I doing wrong?

When I remove the 'disabled' property the checkbox is checked.

```
<FormControlLabel
   control={<Checkbox 
     checked={apiValues.isTrue} 
     onChange={handleFormChange} 
     name="isTrue" 
     disabled={apiValues.isTrue}
     color="secondary"
/>}
label="My Value"
/>
```

api looks like:

```
{
  isTrue: True
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace with

`disabled={!apiValues.isTrue}`

so it becomes

```
<FormControlLabel
   control={<Checkbox 
     checked={apiValues.isTrue} 
     onChange={handleFormChange} 
     name="isTrue" 
     disabled={!apiValues.isTrue}
     color="secondary"
/>}
label="My Value"
/>
```

[Logical Not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT) operator

Comment: that is opposite of what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to disable the checkbox, but keep it checked when True

Comment: oh my bad, what react component library are you using? where does the `Checkbox` component come from? does it have a `defaultValue` prop?